# "Level Generation" algorithm for Mad Virus game

Tags: .net, algorithm, random

I'm making this game on .NET (link: http://www.bubblebox.com/play/puzzle/539.htm ). Everything is fine, except that I don't know how to generate a level that can be solved within N turns. A similar game on Google+ is Flood Fill, but they're square, not hexagon.

EDIT: Here's the explanation about this kind of game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QihKrPLb8e8&feature=player_embedded . Mad Virus is similar, but it has hexagon grid instead, and the number of step is not constant, it increases as the difficulty increases.

Comment: Could you explain gameplay here rather than force others to play similar games? That way will also help you to find an algorithm.

Comment: @yound: I intend, but, well, it's very hard to explain. Even some people play that game still don't understand how it is played. Here's a game instruction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QihKrPLb8e8&feature=player_embedded , but that is square grid, in this game, it's a hexagon grid instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the end result and work backwards.

By the n<sup>th</sup> turn the grid should be uniformly one colour, so start there.  Then pick a connected region of the grid (which contains the top left hexagon) and fill it with some colour.  By repeating this process n times you will obtain a grid that can be solved in n turns.

The colours for each turn should be chosen at random, with the proviso that the same colour should not be chosen twice in a row.  It may turn out that weighting the random choice by how recently each colour has been chosen.

The algorithm to randomly choose each region should (on average) make each region smaller than the last.  It could try to maintain at least one hexagon from each previous fill process.  I suggest you try a few algorithms for area selection, and play test the results.

This process gives you an upper bound on the fastest solution.  The only way I can think to verify the actual minimum number of turns required, is exhaustive search.  Personally I think this sounds like overkill for a level generation algorithm like this.  With an algorithm of the above form, the number of turns will increase heuristically (until n is equal to the fastest solution to the most complex grid).

Comment: Inresting... `Start from the end result and work backwards.` Yes, I've already think it. But I didn't know how to do that. I will try following your hint :) I will reply as soon as I found anything new.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generator that generates an absolutely random map. After generated, you have to  check the map (by using deep search (with some heuristics)) for your conditions (if it can be solved with N moves then apply). Note: verification algorithm didn't have to check all tree of deep-search; it have to check only best leafs.

```
good = false;
while (!good)
{
   map = generate;
   good = verification(map); 
}
```

Comment: No, the map not only can be solved within N turns, but also must be complex enough, so it can not be solved under N - n turns (n maybe from 3 to 5).

Comment: for n from 3 to 5 it isn't solution((

Comment: I'm doing like what you're doing days ago, but my boss didn't satisfied with it. He believe there is a algorithm that can generate a level that meet the conditions.